Is it possible to connect to a SMTP server through proxy?
I'm attempting to connect to SMTP servers through proxies to validate emails.
I've looked into http-proxy-agent, but as I understand, proxies cannot be used with a TCP connection?
My current connection setup:
const client = net.createConnection(25, mxServer, () => {
                client.write("HELO @mail.com\r\n");
                client.write("MAIL FROM:<email_address>\r\n");
                client.write(`RCPT TO:<${email}>\r\n`);
            });


Each MTA (mail transport agent) acts like a store-and-forward proxy. So you can for example use postfix to receive mails and send them later to another MTA.

@Wiimm The main reason for the proxy is for any ip blocks or rate limits. I really just checking if the mail is valid and deliverable. Postfix seems to be a bit out of my depth for what I'm trying to accomplish...

Sure you can proxy the connection, but http-proxy-agent sounds like it speaks HTTP not SMTP (and does not act on the TCP layer either)

You should use SOCKS protocol for SMTP connections rather than HTTP proxies since SOCKS work at TCP level. The following is a solution using Node.js with the SOCKS package:


const SocksClient = require('socks').SocksClient;
const net = require('net');

async function validateEmailThroughProxy(email, mxServer) {
    const socksOptions = {
        proxy: {
            host: 'proxy.example.com', // Your SOCKS proxy host
            port: 1080,               // SOCKS proxy port
            type: 5                   // SOCKS5
        },
        command: 'connect',
        destination: {
            host: mxServer,
            port: 25
        }
    };

    try {
        const info = await SocksClient.createConnection(socksOptions);
        const socket = info.socket;

        // Set encoding for the responses
        socket.setEncoding('utf8');

        // Handle responses
        socket.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('Received:', data);
        });

        // Send SMTP commands
        socket.write("HELO mail.com\r\n");
        socket.write(`MAIL FROM:<sender@example.com>\r\n`);
        socket.write(`RCPT TO:<${email}>\r\n`);

        // Don't forget to handle closing
        socket.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Connection closed');
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    }
}



Note the following:

Ensure you have authorisation to do these checks
Most email servers may block connections due to aggressive validation attempts
Try using well known email validation services rather than direct SMTP
connections
Try as much as possible to implement proper error handling and timeouts
Some servers may provide not so accurate positives or negatives. Beware.

Try the above and see if it solves the problem :-)
